# how to change the color of text in string when I use stringWithFormat function?(iphone)

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, uicolor, stringwithformat

I am using this in a project,

`lblDetail.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@",lblName.text,lblDetail.text];`

in this lblName and lblDetail are both different strings,

Now I want that when I show lblDetail in my view, The text of lblName should be shown in green color.

is this possible ?

I want to do like this

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/269/comment2c.png/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a UILabel that can display some Rich-Text, like a text with the first part in blue and the other in red, you can use my [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel/) class, which is a subclass of UILabel that uses CoreText to draw NSAttributedStrings. (iOS 3.2+)

It is very simple to use and also provide a category for NSAttribtedString that adds some useful methods, like easily change the style of a range of text without the need to know the CoreText attributes constants.

[EDIT] Sorry I didn't realized that Thomas Wanner already mentioned my class in his answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign different colors (or other style attributes like font and size) to different parts of your string, you might be able to use `NSAttributedString` and some extensions that support its drawing, e.g. [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel). Unfortunately you won't get any support out of the box in the iOS SDK.

Comment: thomas ...there is no any file there..only folders are there

Comment: it's exactly what attributed strings are for. However, for your very simple case you might be happy with the workaround of Krypton ;)

Comment: i've updated the link, the repository has moved but it's still the same thing ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a property of a UILabel that let's you set the text color:

```
myLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Is lblDetail always visible in your view, or only after a condition is met?

Comment: I dont want to make whole lblDetail green...lblDetail is made of two string ...from two of them I want to make lblName green ..I have made the text color green as mentioned by you..but not working :(

Comment: Oh I see... I think the only way would be to position them both really close to each other (check their length, calculate the allotted space they take up and ammend the second label's position depending on this) so this way you can set them both in different colors.

Comment: ya...but I cant do this either because..well see this..http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/269/comment2c.png/

Comment: You can still do it my way; person's name label is positioned first and in green. The second part string you could prefix with spaces depending on the length of the person's name string... probably not the best solution but all I can think of I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

**To Give the Font and Color and BackGroundColor to your UILable**

```
lblOfflineCount.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];
lblOfflineCount.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
[lblOfflineCount setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

**for Swift**

```
lblOfflineCount.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
lblOfflineCount.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(14.0)
lblOfflineCount.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```